# LibGDX Error on start with dual-display setup

Tags: java, libgdx

The game works on Windows with fullHD. with a 2 Monitor setup on Linux I am running in the following problem:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't set display mode 3200x1080, fullscreen: true
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglGraphics.setupDisplay(LwjglGraphics.java:150)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:131)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:114)
```

Details about the 2 displays: First FullHD, second 1280x1024

I get the width an hight with the following lines (cfg is the configuration variable)

```
        cfg.width = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width;
        cfg.height = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().height;
```

Any help appriciated. If you need more info, please let me know :D
Is there a way to get the width, height only for the primary display?

Yours,
Florian